# Google Places API input reference location in autocomplete object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-places-api

Does anyone know if the reference of the autocomplete input element is stored anywhere in the autocomplete object used in the Google Maps API?

I'm trying to target this element on the fillInAddress() function that is triggered on the click of a search result. I can not target this element by id, and the class name is a variable. I won't be able to pass a reference as a parameter in the fillInAddress() function either...

I'm hoping I could reference the input element by saying autocomplete.input_element or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I found it...
autocomplete["gm_accessors_"]["place"]["fd"]["gm_accessors_"]["input"]["fd"]["b"]